# Lambda function throwing error if return type is changed from auto to bool

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, auto

I was practicing lambda functions in C++, following code works fine

```
void insertionSort(int* a, int size, bool reverse=false) {
    auto comp = [](int a, int b, bool reverse) {
        return reverse ? a > b : b < a;
    };
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int current = a[i];
        cout << current <<endl;
        int j = i-1;
        while (j >= 0 && comp(current, a[j], reverse)) {
           a[j+1] = a[j]; //shift right
           j--;
        }
        a[j+1] = current;
    }
    show(a, size); //another function which prints all elements of a
}
```

but if I change

```
    auto comp = [](int a, int b, bool reverse) {
```

with

```
    bool comp = [](int a, int b, bool reverse) {
```

GCC compiler throws following error while compiling
 `error: 'comp' cannot be used as a function 29 |   while (j >= 0 && comp(current, a[j], reverse)) {`

So is this expected? What is general rule? Shall I always specify return type as `auto`?

Comment: auto comp = [](int a, int b, bool reverse) -> bool {}

this is how you declare lambda with bool return type.
the auto you are changing is the type of the lambda itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the 1st code snippet, `comp`'s type is the type of the [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), it's a unique unnamed class type, (that's why we use `auto`, we can't specify the type explicitly). Note that it's not the return type of the lambda (i.e. `bool`).

If you want to specify the return type of the lambda explicitly you can

```
auto comp = [](int a, int b, bool reverse) -> bool {
//                                         ^^^^^^^
```

BTW: Non-capturing lambdas could convert to function pointer and then convert to `bool` implicitly. So if you change the type of `comp` to `bool` its value is always `true`. As the error message said, you just can't use it as functor.

Comment: Related: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/lambda-expressions-in-cpp?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 2):

When you write `auto comp = [](int a, int b, bool reverse) {`, comp has the unique type lambda aka, C++ compiler creates a struct names comp. But when you write `bool comp = [](int a, int b, bool reverse) {`, comp has the type bool and can only take bool values.